# What ML algorithm to use in order to find a pattern between file name and the content of the file?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, regression, hierarchical-clustering

I am working on a ML project and got stuck on what approach to take in that problem:

I have a table (.csv file) that contains in a column 'file' list of all my **.txt files** that are called BAM_xxxx, where xxxx is a combination of digits and letters. All other columns of the table are functions, that is **function1, function2, function3,...., function30.**

If the function is present in the .txt file there is 1 in the table in that cell, if not there is 0. It looks somehow like this:

| index | file | function1 | function2 | ... | function30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BAM_123A.txt | 1 | 1 | ... | 0 |
| 2 | BAM_CD0X.txt | 0 | 1 | ... | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1000 | BAM_1A3B.txt | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 |

**I want to investigate if there is a relationship between the name of .txt file (that is: xxxx) and the functions present in the file. What ML Algorithm would be best for that task?**

I was thinking about some kind of clustering (though dont have an idea yet what how would the clusters look like) such as Random Forest, ut I suppose first I need to create features from the file names somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Finding a meaningful relationship between file names and their content may not be guaranteed, as the relationship could be weak or nonexistent. If the ML algorithms do not provide satisfactory results, you may need to consider alternative approaches or gather additional data to enhance your analysis.

Since you want to find relationships between the file name features and the presence/absence of functions, you can use the following ML algorithms:

**Supervised learning:** If you have a specific function that you want to predict based on the file name features, you can use classification algorithms like **Logistic Regression**, **Random Forest** or **Support Vector Machines (SVM)**.

**Unsupervised learning:** If you don't have a specific function to predict and just want to find patterns or groupings in the data, you can use clustering algorithms like **K-Means**, **DBSCAN**, or **Hierarchical Clustering**.

Have a look at the python module [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you need a machine learning algorithm for your problem here. It's always a good approach to conduct some statistical analysis to gain a good understanding of your data

### Correlation tests

You should start by measuring the correlation between the file_name and your other variables or conducting other independancy tests first (Pearson, Kendall-Tau, etc). (you'll have to encode your file_name to numerical space to do that), but it should give you a good idea, if your file_name is actually independant or not of your content or features (if that's the case then it's useless to apply any machine learning algorithm to predict your file_name)

### Machine learning approach

If you determine that your features / content and target aren't exactly independant, you can then go through the machine learning route.
For example if you're trying to predict the file_name from the content of the file itself. Then it might be set up as a classification problem, if your file_name has a specified cardinality (eg : file_name is either 'fileA', 'fileB', or 'fileC'). That way you can use supervised or unsupervised learning methods as specified in the previous answer.